# F# Singleton and disposing internal resources

Tags: f#

In my AWS lambda function, I need to access secret values from the AWS Secret manager. I am using the [AWSSDK.SecretsManager.Caching package](https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-caching-net) to achieve this. To get the most out of the provided caching mechanism, I have decided to create a simple singleton wrapper around the `SecretsManagerCache`:

```
namespace MyProject

open Amazon.SecretsManager.Extensions.Caching

type SecretsProvider private () =
  let secretsCache = new SecretsManagerCache()
  
  static let instance =
    SecretsProvider()
  
  static member Instance = instance
  
  member this.GetSecretString key =
    secretsCache.GetSecretString key
```

This seems to be fine, but there is one thing that concerns me. The `SecretsManagerCache` implements `IDisposable`. I have tried writing

```
  use secretsCache = new SecretsManagerCache()
```

but that gives me a compiler error saying `'use' bindings are not permitted in primary constructors`. Is it OK to simply use the `let` keyword? Or should I implement a finalizer?

```
  override this.Finalize() =
    secretsCache.Dispose()
```

Or is there another way how to safely dispose an internal resource from a singleton?

Comment: This looks like translated C# code. In F#, a module is already static, so any fields are static themselves. You could just set the value to a field and only expose `GetSecretString`. A more F#-y way would be to use memoization, and initialise the client on the first call

Comment: I found the Singleton implementation [here](http://blogs.tedneward.com/patterns/singleton-fsharp/). Please, could you elaborate on how to do this in a more F#y way? This is my first F# project, so everything is new to me.

Comment: In a module `let Instance=new SecretsManagerCache()` would create a static read-only field. The C# code has to create a class because C# has no modules. There's no need for the singleton wrapper. A *far* cleaner solution would be to *not* use a singleton though, and pass the instance as a parameter wherever needed. You could create the instance in the entry point with eg `use secretsCache = new SecretsManagerCache()` and ensure it got disposed when the application exits

Comment: If you use .NET Core, or use the .NET Core configuration libraries in .NET Old applications, you can [integrate AWS Secrets management](https://andrewlock.net/secure-secrets-storage-for-asp-net-core-with-aws-secrets-manager-part-1/) directly into the application's configuration, just like any other config provider. This would allow you to switch from AWS Secrets to Azure KeyVault to a database or anything else simply by changing the provider

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your SecretsManager in a SecretsProvider like you have done but implementing `IDisposable` to dispose of the SecretsManager object.

```
type ISecretsProvider =
    abstract member GetSecretString : key:string -> string

type SecretsProvider () =
    let secretsCache = new SecretsManagerCache()
    
  interface IDisposable with
        member x.Dispose() = () 
             secretsCache.Dispose()

  interface ISecretsProvider with
      member this.GetSecretString key =
        secretsCache.GetSecretString key
```

You can then declare your dependencies in your functions e.g:

```
f : ISecretsProvider->int->'T
g : 'T->unit
h : ISecretsProvider->unit
```

For a console application you can provide the only instance of this dependency in your entry point function:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
    let main _ = 
        use sp = new SecretsProvider()
        let a = f sp 2
        g a
        h sp
```

If you're using ASP.NET core you can do so with configureServices:

```
let configureServices (services : IServiceCollection) =
    services.AddSingleton<ISecretsProvider, SecretsProvider>() |> ignore
```

Update: As Discussed with @Panagiotis Kanavos the SecretsProvider may not be necessary. You may use SecretsManager instead of ISecretsProvider an SecretsProvider in the above code.   However, to achieve loose coupling interfaces are good practice, this will depend more on the complexity and goals of your overall solution.

Comment: This is wrapping yet another wrapper over the wrapper. When using DI *no* wrapper is needed. Simply registering `SecretsManagerCache` will get it disposed when it goes out of scope. The original C# code creates a singleton simply by setting a read-only static field. In F#, this can be done by simply using `let` to set a field. This will create a static read-only field

Comment: Since `SecretsManagerCache` already implements IDisposable, the OP's code would be simpler if the cache was created in the entry point and injected instead of using a singleton: `use sp= new SecretsManagerCache()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  for dependency injection you need an Interface I don't think SecretsManagerCache has one, that's the sole reason for wrapping.

Comment: No you don't. It works with any type. Interfaces are used when you want to inject different implementations for the same interface

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos in any case it's good practice since you may want to change the implementation. for getting your secrets.  Maybe you won't use the Awssecretsmanager maybe you use a vault etc.

Comment: You just touched on one of the greatest annoyances with F# - it pretends interfaces aren't needed and forces people to explicitly cast to the interface before using it. What you described does make sense though, and is already handled  by .NET Core's configuration subsystem. AWS Secrets Manager [can be integrated directly](https://andrewlock.net/secure-secrets-storage-for-asp-net-core-with-aws-secrets-manager-part-1/) into a .NET Core app's configuration

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Why do you think F# pretends interfaces aren't needed? I really don't think that's the case at all.

Comment: It requires explicit implementation and explicit casting before they can be used. This makes using F# with libraries that expose interfaces a big pain - you now have to type every parameter, cast back and forth. In Scott Wlaschin's interface article the [Using Interfaces](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/interfaces/#using-interfaces) section shows explicit typing even in the "automatic" case.

Comment: This makes using eg Dataflow block very tricky as each block implements multiple interfaces like ITargetBlock, ISinkBlock etc. You end up writing *more* code in F# than you would in C#